# How can I have only inner cell spacing? (Remove outer cell spacing)

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, cells

I have a table in Word 2013 with 0.45cm cell spacing applied to the table:

[image]

For the purposes of this question, I've turned on some extra borders:

[image]

How can I remove the "outer" spacing, and just keep the "inner" spacing?

The aim is to have `Title` aligned to the left, and top.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like there is a way to selectively choose which cells the spacing is applied to, it's all or nothing. Furthermore Word doesn't allow a negative default cell margin so you can't offset it that way.

You mentioned that you added extra borders for your demonstration, I'm assuming that the outside border is normally invisible? In that case you could work around this problem by making table indent from left a negative value so it fits in with the margin and then reduce any spacing on the paragraph above to shift the table closer. I think this is as good as you will get it.

[image]